# Recognizing if further expression execution can be skipped

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, virtual-machine, evaluation

I have such expression:

```
(a and b or c) and d
```

How would I recognize it's further execution doesn't make sense. For example when

```
a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 1
```

it doesn't make sense to perform the outer most *`(...) and d`* becouse the whole expression will be false after the `(a and b or c)` return false.

So I'm trying to find a general rule that allows me to analyze expression and based on that, find those parts of expressions which execution is crucial for the whole expression and skip further execution if necessary. Below is hypothetical code of stack based virtual machine with the expression i'm starting from

```
ld a
ld b
and
ld c
or
ld d
and
```

with this what I would like to achieve:

```
ld a
ld b
and
ld c
or
jmpf outOfQuery ;;jump if false
ld d
and
outOfQuer:
```

Comment: Usually short-circuiting `and` and `or` operators are simply compiled to conditional branches (`x and y` === `if x then y else false`, `x or y` === `if x then true else y`), not to `and` or `or` instructions.

Comment: This is fine for scalar compares but if `a, b, c or d` are expressions you may want to review lazy, or deferred, evaluation along with short-circuting.

Comment: 1. Why downvotted? 2. @sepp2k, Can you put your comment as reply? I would like to mark your response as solution becouse that's what I was looking for. The answer is short circuiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of not evaluating the right operand of Boolean operators when the result is already determined by the left operand, is known as short circuiting. It is usually implemented by compiling the `and` and `or` operators to the same code as conditional expressions:

- `a and b` would be equivalent to `a ? b : false` (or `a ? b : a`)
- `a or b` would be equivalent to `a ? true : b` (or `a ? a : b`)

So the generated byte- and/or machine code would not contain any `and` or `or` instructions, but just a conditional branch.